# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise | NuGet Exception | Initializing Part Nuget.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSolutionManager | GetFullVsVersionString

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

While attempting to build or open a project in Visual Studio 2015 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 which I recently installed, I keep getting errors around nuget package management. Whenever I build the project the first time after opening VS, I get the error message below. I also get it when I try to open the nuget package manager dialog. Anyone else experience this?

> An exception was thrown while initializing part
> "Nuget.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSolutionManager".
> GetFullVsVersionString must be called on the UI thread.

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 1]

---

Related Thread :

[Visual Studio 2015 Initializing Part Nuget.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSolutionManager must be called on UI Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678601/visual-studio-2015-initializing-part-nuget-packagemanagement-visualstudio-vsolut)
Solution :

> It appears reinstalling Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio in the
> Extensions & Tools dialog may have fixed it.

I did this solution - But problem exist still!!!!!!

Comment: When i open VS solution from project's sln file directly error appears. But when i open new visual studio & open nuget settings & open project from Open Project menu error vanished.
What is going on?

Comment: What is your project type? Does this issue still happen in a new project?

Comment: ASP.Net Web Application.
No - Not happen in a new project.
I have many created projects.
All of them were ok - but suddenly that error appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actually**, this issue might be caused by other third party extensions, components caches, nuget caches or VS environment, I suggest you could try the following suggestions:

**Suggestions**

**1)** disable any third party installed extensions exclude under Tools-->Extensions and Updates except **NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015**.

**Then**, uninstall **NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015** extension.

**2)** close VS,

**a)** delete all nuget caches under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages` and also delete the `nuget.config under` C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`

**Besides**, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of the project folder.

**b)** delete all component caches under

`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

**c)** then restart VS and then install nuget extension directly from this [VS marketplace website](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2015).

**3)** try to run `devenv /safemode` under **Developer Command Prompt for VS2015** to start VS and then test again. This mode is a pure, initial vs environment when you first installed.

**4)** repair VS from the **Control Panel**-->**Programs**-->right click on VS2015-->**Change**-->**Repair**