# Visual Studio 2015 - Nuget Exception - GetFullVsVersionString must be called on the UI thread

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2015, nuget

While attempting to build or open a project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I keep getting errors around nuget package management.
Whenever I build the project the first time after opening VS, I get the error message below.
I also get it when I try to open the nuget package manager dialog.
Anyone else experience this?

```
An exception was thrown while initializing part
"Nuget.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSolutionManager".
GetFullVsVersionString must be called on the UI thread.
```

[image: 1]

---

Here is another thread in stack about this issue :

[Visual Studio 2015 Initializing Part Nuget.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSolutionManager must be called on UI Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678601/visual-studio-2015-initializing-part-nuget-packagemanagement-visualstudio-vsolut)

And here is in github :
[GetFullVsVersionString must be called on the UI thread #3419](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3419)

People say install [this plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kzu.FixNuGetGetFullVsVersionStringmustbecalledontheUIt) for fix this issue.
But when i open that url i face this error :

> We're sorry, the page you requested cannot be found!

> In `VisualStudio 2015 -> Tools -> Extensions and updates -> Online`:
> Search for the string: "*Fix NuGet GetFullVsVersionString must be
> called on the UI thread*" and install the given fix.
>
> Alternatively you can download the fix at : [GetFullVsVersionString
> fix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kzu.FixNuGetGetFullVsVersionStringmustbecalledontheUIt)
>
> Now in February 2018, the latest NuGet Package Manager version
> **3.4.4.1321** does not have the fix included, so the patch must be applied.
>
> As Steve Greene's answer describes, I also had the Telerik extension
> installed, so that might have caused the problem.

I searched that phrase in VS - But could n't find anything.
Also `GetFullVsVersionString fix` does n't exist any more.
I also reinstalled nuget package manager - no help.
What is the solution?

---

**EDIT 1 :**
When i delete `.vs hidden folder` and open VS error vanished.
but when i close VS & reopen it again i face that error again.
What is wrong about `.vs hidden` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several suggestions:

**1)** disable any third installed party extensions under **Tools**--> **Extensions and Updates**--> **Installed** to check whether there is an extension that caused this issue.

**2)** Close VS, delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

You can also delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of the project.

**Then**, restart VS to test again.

**Further**, try to reinstall **Nuget Package Manager** extension again.

**3)** restore VS environment, enter `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0`

And you can just rename the `14.0` folder to another name like `VS2015_Backup`(just make a backup for your VS2015 environment).

**Then**, restart VS to test the issue.

**4)** open **Control Panel**-->**Programs and Features**-->right-click on **VS2015 Program**-->**change**-->**Repair**

Comment: What was that GetFullVsVersionString fix extension? Why did they remove it from marketplace?

Comment: When i delete .vs hidden folder and open VS error vanished.  but when i close VS & reopen it again i face that error again.
What is wrong about .vs hidden folder?

Comment: `.vs` hidden folder stores the record and options of your local project. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897191/what-is-the-vs-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio-solutions). This is equivalent to initializing your project. However, since this problem occurs the second time, you should try to restore VS.

Comment: I did not know that extension since it is too old. And maybe it is not suitable.