# Visual Studio 2015 - Nuget Exception - GetFullVsVersionString must be called on the UI thread - Telerik Extension Problem

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2015, nuget, telerik

While attempting to build or open a project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I keep getting errors around nuget package management.
Whenever I build the project the first time after opening VS, I get the error message below.
I also get it when I try to open the nuget package manager dialog.
Here is the error :

```
An exception was thrown while initializing part
"Nuget.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSolutionManager".
GetFullVsVersionString must be called on the UI thread.
```

[image: 1]

---

I figured out problem is from telerik extensions.
I cleared VS log and grabed that error like this :
[ActivityLog.xml](https://gofile.io/d/hFUwx7)
How can i fix it without disabling Telerik Extensions?

---

**Edit :**
Telerik extensions are latest version - I uninstalled them & Installed them again.
Problem was there after reinstall.
Those extensions are :   **ASP.NET - WinForm - MVC** (3 Extensions)

Comment: why do you [ask the same again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65906801/1466046)?

Comment: That answer was before Edits - This question is totally different & it is related to telerik.

Comment: remove several extensions until you find the cause. if it is telerik, submit it to their support. It looks like it is time to update to VS2019

Comment: I can't understand why VS 2019 has such that size?
Also i had some issues for offline installation. This is why i do n't like VS 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you could first clean ComponentModelCache and do a initial operation to VS.

If the issue persists, the only issue is related to **Telerik** extension with **VS2015** and you have to [contact with the Team](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TelerikInc.TelerikSilverlightVSExtensions&ssr=false#qna).